# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' during stateful DoFn

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, encoding, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using a stateful and timely DoFn to process data 2 seconds after the end of the fixed window I am implementing.

I have tested a reproducible example of my code inside the Apache Beam playground. My data is in `KV[str, str]` format as an input to the DoFn. The only difference I can think of between the playground and my code is that the playground uses a DirectRunner and I am using a DataflowRunner.

Before my DoFn I have another DoFn that mutates the input PCollection into the format the stateful DoFn is expecting:

```py
class AddKeys(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    def process(self, element):
        data = element["data"]

        for setting in self.settings:
            if setting["data"] == data:
                yield [
                    ("tuple key 1",
                     setting["tuple key 1"]),
                    ("tuple key 2", setting["tuple key 2"]),
                    ("tuple key 3", setting["tuple key 3"]),
                    ("element", str(element))
                ]
```

Then my stateful DoFn should take the output and process it:

```py
class ProcessCollection(beam.DoFn):
    EXPIRY_TIMER = TimerSpec('expiry', TimeDomain.WATERMARK)
    BUFFER_STATE = BagStateSpec(
        'buffer', ListCoder(StrUtf8Coder()))

    def process(self, element,
                timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(EXPIRY_TIMER),
                window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
                buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):

        timer.set(window.end + Duration(seconds=2))

        buffer.add(str(element))

    @on_timer(EXPIRY_TIMER)
    def expiry(self, buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):
        events = buffer.read()

        for event in events:
            yield ''.join(event)

        buffer.clear()
```

Calling DoFn method:

```py
# continue with processing & branch to stateful DoFn
extra_processing = (
    raw_data_processing
    | "Add Group Keys"
    >> beam.Map(
        lambda message: add_group_key(
            message, SETTINGS)
        )
    | "Fixed Window"
    >> beam.WindowInto(
        window.FixedWindows(self.window_length),
        # if message late by 700ms, still accept
        allowed_lateness=window.Duration(seconds=0.7)
    )
    | "Group" >> beam.GroupByKey()
    | "Process Further" >> beam.ParDo(OtherDoFn(SETTINGS, CONFIG))
)

# process data with stateful DoFn
(
    extra_processing
    | "Add Keys" >> beam.ParDo(AddKeys(SETTINGS)).with_output_types(KV[str, str])
    | "Process Collection" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessCollection())
    | 'Log' >> beam.LogElements(with_timestamp=True)
)
```

The error I receive from Google Cloud is:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 429, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' [while running 'Add Keys-ptransform-51']
```

[Full stack trace in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xCxQYq5X) due to size

Can anyone determine why this might be occurring?

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Added in a pastebin due to the size of the trace.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you call both DoFns? The error is most likely there (some `with_output_types` or similar thing).

Comment: @CaptainNabla Yes, added in edit. Let me know if you need anything further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your assumption why it does work with the DirectRunner, because this runner does not encode anything.

I am not familiar with `KV[...]`, since I have never used that function and/or heard of it. So I am not sure what you are telling Beam to encode with this. Nevertheless, I encountered your error before and it is definitely caused by a missmatch of the argument within `with_output_types` (or `with_input_types` for that matter) and what you are actually returning.

In order to fix your problem, you would need to add the correct type hints. Thought, I am not sure what they are in your case, since you are returning a list of tuples with strings..? However, you can verify that this is indeed causing the issue, by starting the pipeline without the `with_output_types` - then Dataflow should stop showing the error.

**Edit:**

Stateful DoFns work per key (and window). If you want to buffer (and eventually join - as defined in your `ProcessCollection`) all of the incoming data, then you would need to create a dummy key. This can be anything (int, bool, str), you just have to make sure it is the same for every datapoint, e.g.

```
yield (
   "my_dummy_key",
   [
       ("tuple key 1", setting["tuple key 1"]),
       ("tuple key 2", setting["tuple key 2"]),
       ("tuple key 3", setting["tuple key 3"]),
       ("element", str(element))
   ]
)
```

By doing so, the **whole list** will **always added** to your **buffer**.

Alternatively, if you want to join only the settings which belong to a specific key,  you would need to rewrite your `AddKey` and make it dynamic

```
yield (
    self.get_dynamic_key(),    # the dynamic key method needs to be tailored to your use case / data
    setting[self.get_dynamic_key()]
)
```

This **results in** `n` **different buffers** (where `n` is the number of dynamic keys) and only those belonging to the same key are then buffered and joined within `ProcessCollection`.

Comment: KV is a type that in my case the ParDo would only accept inputs in. See [this guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-type-safety/#parameterized-type-hints) on ensuring type safety for reference. I don't actually mind what my types are in this case, all I'm trying to do is to be able to get the data into the ParDo and using this type was the closest I got without it throwing an error.
The actual data is in form: `tuple(str, str, str, dict)`, but I had to modify it in order for the ParDo to not shout at me. Is that clearer?

Comment: I've just removed the type hint and I get: `ValueError: Input elements to the transform <ParDo(PTransform) label=[Process Collection]> with stateful DoFn must be key-value pairs.`

Comment: Just telling in the Typehints that you are sending a key-value pair to a stateful DoFn is not enough. The state in `ProcessCollection` (e.g., `buffer`) is created for each individual key. What is the key in your case? If it is `"tuple key 1"`, then you should yield in `AddKeys` something like `yield ("tuple key 1", ([<your original outputlist>]) )`

Comment: Are you saying I should yield them individually? E.gs. `yield ("tuple key 1", "example")` `yield ("tuple key 2", "example")` `yield ("tuple key 3", "example")`? I'm attempting to use a ListCoder now but i'm running into deterministic errors.

Comment: That depends on your use case. Do you want to buffer and join all incoming data? Then just add a dummy key (does not matter what str/int/bool). Else make it a meaningful key and 'group' the data accordingly

Comment: I've edited my post, to make it (hopefully) clearer

Comment: This is brilliant, I've worked it out and is now working from your solution. Thank you.